# PHP regular expression to filter attribute from tag

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I use a PHP script to convert some custom tags to valid Bootstrap tags as I need to put them in many script and want only one place to manage settings.

Converting e.g. `<well>` to `<div class="well">` is simple, but what pattern should I have if I want to convert `<well title="hello">` to `<div class="well"><h4>hello</h4>`?

So I need to be able to recognize the tag with a attribute that can have any value, but I also need to have that value. Regex remains a mystery to me once things get a little more complex...

Thanks!

Comment: How do you differentiate between custom tags and conventional tags ?

Comment: @noob: I avoid using conventional tags..

Comment: There could be more attributes other than `title` ? If yes what to do with their values ?

Comment: You just need to use `(...)` around the pattern the value of which you want to re-use and use a backreference to it. Say, `<win\s+title="([^"]*)">` -> `<div class="well"><h4>$1</h4>`

Comment: @Wiktor: I preferred your solution over the one below, to this is the correct answer to me! Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, I will not post it since using regex to manipulate HTML is strongly discouraged and any answer with that is downvoted (in the majority of cases). I'd rather delete the post.

Comment: And why is it discouraged? I use custom tags to create some boilerplate code. I do not manipulate valid html tags..

Answer (score 0):

It's not very dynamic, but works for this specific example ... is it what you need?

```
$re = "/\\<([\\w]+) ?(([\\w]+)\\=\\\"([\\w]+)\\\")\\>/"; 
$str = "<well title=\"hello\">";
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
$new_tag = '<div class="'.$matches['1'].'"><h4>'.$matches[4].'</h4></div>';
echo "\n".$new_tag;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the solution that Wiktor proposed had a better fit in my code (and was more straightforward imho)